# Custom admin menu redirecting to dashboard in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7, admin-controller

I have created custom admin menu but when clicking on the menu it is redirecting to dashboard.

Here is the xml within `etc/adminhtml/menu.xml` :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
     <menu>
       <add id="Cubet_RMA::rma" title="Cubet RMA" resource="Cubet_RMA::rma" module="Cubet_RMA"  sortOrder="20"/>
       <add id="Cubet_RMA::managerma" title="Manage RMA" resource="Cubet_RMA::Rmaadmin" parent="Cubet_RMA::rma" action="rmaadmin/rmaadmin/index" module="Cubet_RMA" sortOrder="20"/>
   </menu>
 </config>
```

Here is the xml within `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
      <router id="admin">
        <route id="rmaadmin" frontName="rmaadmin">
          <module name="Cubet_RMA"/>
       </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Here is the `Controller/Adminhtml/Rmaadmin/Index.php` code:

```
<?php
 namespace Cubet\RMA\Controller\Adminhtml\Rmaadmin;
 class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'ListReturns';

protected $resultPageFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{
   $return = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
   // $return->setActiveMenu('Cubet_RMA::rma');
   // $return->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Manage RMA Requests')));
   return $return;
}
}
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below code.

I tried the code in my local machine. It was working perfectly.

> Step1 - Creating registration.php in the following path
>   app/code/Cubet/RMA

```
<?php

    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Cubet_RMA',
        __DIR__
    );
```

> Step2 - Creating module.xml in the following path
>   app/code/Cubet/RMA/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Cubet_RMA" setup_version="1.0.2">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> Step3 - Creating routes.xml in the following path
>   app/code/Cubet/RMA/etc/adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="rmaadmin" frontName="rmaadmin">
            <module name="Cubet_RMA" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Step4 - Creating menu.xml in the following path
>   app/code/Cubet/RMA/etc/adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>

        <update id="Cubet_RMA::CubetRMA" title="RMA" resource="Cubet_RMA::Rma" module="Cubet_RMA" sortOrder="300" />
        <add id="Cubet_RMA::rma" title="RMA" module="Cubet_RMA" sortOrder="50" resource="Cubet_RMA::Rmaadmin" parent="Cubet_RMA::CubetRMA" action="rmaadmin/index" />

    </menu>
</config>
```

> Step5 - Creating Index.php in the following path
>   /var/www/html/Magento-CE-2.1.6/app/code/Cubet/RMA/Controller/Adminhtml/Index

```
<?php

namespace Cubet\RMA\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "welcome"; exit;

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Run Setup Upgrad.

Clear Cache.

Give folder permission.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the `isallowed` method:-

```
protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Companyname_Module::controllername');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking on Magento 2.1.7, your code will work. However, to make the current code better, we need to make some changes:

Create ACL:

app/code/Cubet/RMA/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Cubet_RMA::rma">
                <resource id="Cubet_RMA::managerma" title="Manager RMA" translate="title" sortOrder="30"/>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Set `const ADMIN_RESOURCE`: the resource id in `acl.xml`. For example:

```
const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Cubet_RMA::rma';
```

Comment: Thanks Khoa TruongDinh! it was the version issue I guess. Like you mentioned it is working on 2.1.7. You saved my day!

Comment: In your case, seem that you need to create `acl.xml` and change the constant `const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Cubet_RMA::rma';`. And then, check again.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Magento use “secret key” for each request on the adminhtml. You only need to disable that option from the backend.

Stores => Configuration => Advanced => Admin => Security => Add Secret Key to URLs

This works for me

Source:

https://www.codealist.net/magento-2-custom-admin-controller-action-redirected-to-dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

Disable the use of "secret key" in the backend would be a security risk. Instead, add the following to your Index class.

```
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Cubet_RMA::rma';

    /**
     * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $_publicActions = ['view', 'index'];
```

If you check the code in vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order.php, you will see that's how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a New Registration.php**
navigate to the file in Magento2Root/app/code/Cloudways/Adminmenu/ and add the code below to it:

```html
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Cloudways_Adminmenu',
   __DIR__
);
```

**Create a Module.xml**
Create a module.xml file in Cloudways/Adminmenu/etc/ with the following code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd"> <module name="Cloudways_Adminmenu" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

**Declare Route**
you need to create the new file named routes.xml in the path app\code\Cloudways\Adminmenu\etc\routes.xml

I added the routes.xml file in the folder named admin html, because I want these codes only to apply to the admin.

```html
?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:app/etc/routes.xsd">
  <route id="admin">
  <route id="admin" frontName=”mainmenu”>
  <module name="Cloudways_Adminmenu"/>
</router>
</router>
</config>
```

**Create a New Menu Item**
Create a new file menu.xml in Cloudways/Adminmenu/etc/adminhtml/ and add the following content to it:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd>  
<menu>
       <add id="Cloudways_Adminmenu::first_level_demo"
            title="Cloudways Admin Menu”
module="Cloudways_Adminmenu"
sortOrder="20"
resource="Magento_Backend::content" />
       <add id="Cloudways_Adminmenu::second_level_demo"
            title="Sub Menu”
module="Cloudways_Adminmenu"
sortOrder="1"
action="menuitem/index/index"
parent="Cloudways_Adminmenu::first_level_demo"
            resource="Magento_Backend::content" />
  </menu>
</config>
```

**Clear the Magento Cache!**

```html
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```